# How to create the Dynamic table in Lightning component

Tags: lightning, table

I am new to Lightning, I wants to make this below table dynamic, So once the searchResult will be having respected data i can show it dynamically by using Iteration tag. Column name and Rows should be populate dynamically. Can anyone please help me out.

```
<!-- TABLE CONTENT--> 
<table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_cell-buffer">
    <thead>
        <tr class="slds-text-title_caps">                  
           <th scope="col">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Name">Name</div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Status">Status</div>
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Approver">Approver</div>
            </th>                   
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> 
        <!--### display all records of searchResult attribute by aura:iteration ###-->
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.searchResult}" var="acc" indexVar="count" >
            <tr>
                 <td>
                    <div class="slds-truncate">{!acc.Name}</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="slds-truncate">{!acc.Status__c}</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="slds-truncate">{!acc.Approver__c}</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </aura:iteration>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: what problem are you facing exactly? please provide a problem description, as well as what you have tried to resolve it. thanks

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried so far its not much different from a vf page

Comment: Why not leverage the builtin `<lightning:dataTable>` component? You can certainly add your own filter mechanism outside the data table.